# Многомерные массивы

Tags: javascript

Как найти индекс элемента в многомерном массиве, напишите, пожалуйста, крайне простую программу.

Comment: Идём по внешнему циклу, в котором есть внутренний цикл, по которому тоже идём, перебирая индексы, и сравниваем элементы массива с необходимым значением, если находим равные, возвращаем индекс внешнего или внутреннего цикла или же объект, содержащий оба индекса и выходим из циклов.

P.S. вас не волнует, что из-за таких вопросов ваша репутации стремится к -∞?

Comment: Не очень, я новичок, так что мне главное научиться.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr=new Array();
var res=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<=arr[i].length;j++){
        if(el==arr[i][j]){
            res[0]=i;res[1]=j;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(res[0]!=null){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ведь эти записи эквиваленты?

    var arr=new Array();
    var arr=[];

гуру js поправьте меня.

Comment: Да, эквивалентны. Какая разница как определять его? Не понимаю сути комментария

Comment: @stck например в случае строки запись `new String()` и `""` **не** эквивалентны (если быть точным - не совсем). Хотя да, в случае с массивами разницы нет, разве-что принято использовать короткую нотацию `[]`

Comment: Спасибо за поправку, на будущее учту.